# Prevent inference of union type when using an indexed access type inside a generic

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an ergonomic generic interface in TypeScript that allows the signature of a function inside an object to be inferred based on the presence and type of an adjacent (neighboring) key.

I have implemented the following, and my solution is partially functional for my usecase:

```
interface BaseColumnDefinition<T extends Record<string, any>> {
    label?: string;
    key?: keyof T | undefined;
}

interface KeylessColumnDefinition<T extends Record<string, any>> extends BaseColumnDefinition<T> {
    key?: undefined;
    render: (value: T) => JSX.Element;
}

interface KeyedColumnDefinition<T extends Record<string, any>> extends BaseColumnDefinition<T> {
    key: keyof T;
    render: (value: T[this["key"]]) => JSX.Element;
}

type ColumnDefinition<T extends Record<string, any>> =
    | KeyedColumnDefinition<T>
    | KeylessColumnDefinition<T>;

const definitionWithoutKey: ColumnDefinition<{ name: string; id: string; value: number }> = {
    label: "Name",
    render: (value) => <></>, //correctly infers the type of render is (value: {name: string, id: string, value: number}) => JSX.Element 
};

const definitionWithKey: ColumnDefinition<{ name: string; id: string; value: number }> = {
    label: "Name",
    key: "value",
    render: (value) => <></>, //should infer a type of (value: number) => JSX.Element, instead infers the union of types from the T parameter i.e. (value: string | number) => JSX.Element
};
```

If there is any way that I can engineer this such that I get correct signature inference based on the value  of "key" inside the object, then that is what I would like to achieve.

Comment: You need to pass the key's value as a generic and then use `this[Key]`. This of course, requires duping the key's value as both a type and a value. If you want to get around that, then you need a helper function to infer it for you.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NaZGEm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That solves it perfectly, thanks! I had tried to work with an additional generic parameter, but I hadn't been able to fix the ColumnDefinition. That's what did it.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want `ColumnDefinition<T>` to include a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object where each property `K` in `keyof T` shows up as its own union member.  So, for example, `ColumnDefinition{ name: string; id: string; value: number;}>` should be equivalent to

```
type MyColDef = {
  key: "name";
  render: (value: string) => JSX.Element;
} | {
  key: "id";
  render: (value: string) => JSX.Element;
} | {
  key: "value";
  render: (value: number) => JSX.Element;
} | {
  key?: undefined;
  render: (value: { name: string; id: string; value: number; }) => JSX.Element;
}
```

But your `KeyedColumnDefinition<T>` mixes all properties together.  The type `keyof T` is a union of keys, and `this["key"]` will become a union of properties.  TypeScript does not automatically distribute interfaces across unions; if you want such behavior you'll need to make it happen yourself.

One way to do this is to add a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) parameter `K extends keyof T` to `KeyedColumnDefinition<T, K>` so that it corresponds to a single known key:

```
interface KeyedColumnDefinition<
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends keyof T> extends BaseColumnDefinition<T> {
  key: K;
  render: (value: T[K]) => JSX.Element;
}
```

And then `ColumnDefinition<T>` should have a union of `KeyedColumnDefinition<T, K>` for each `K` in keyof T`.  One way to write that is as a *distributive object* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which is when you [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of a type and immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the result with the full key set to get a union.  That is,` {[K in KS]: F}[KS]`will distribute`F`over unions in`KS`.  In our case` KS`is`keyof T`and`F`is`KeyedColumnDefinition<T, K>`:

```
type ColumnDefinition<T extends Record<string, any>> =
  | { [K in keyof T]: KeyedColumnDefinition<T, K> }[keyof T]
  | KeylessColumnDefinition<T>;
```

With this definition things work as you expect:

```
const definitionWithoutKey: ColumnDefinition<{ name: string; id: string; value: number }> = {
  label: "Name",
  render: (value) => <></>
  //      ^? (parameter) value: { name: string; id: string; value: number; }
};

const definitionWithKey: ColumnDefinition<{ name: string; id: string; value: number }> = {
  label: "Name",
  key: "value",
  render: (value) => <></>
  //       ^? (parameter) value: number;
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEUBnJAYQgBsBXENQAiSTDWAxgEagB4AKnCQAPOtQAm7REjTR1s9jCg0A5gBo4KagE8AfLbgBvcnDi8UAIyS8A-AC44Q2NqEwpXAGska384SOsITDhFAB84fg0xGiR1CgBfSho6BiY4AGko3iR2dh4BIVFxaklpOUUVNU1tXSh9INMLKzsHdqQNLTZOWsERTKapGQUHZwiomPT1WeywuCIMqACACgA3FAEkAPkASjgAXgcAKQBlAA0AOgBRSpBRmDzKAto9EYaGY5Ws2Sm9VmzQWLiSSlUo06yG6vSM-UsNlsZjhpQRHS0cQSSWGiLGrA43D40waEnmrSWcLiAVK212G32cGOp345ySAG1SgBda53OBPN6fJDfWh-cgwaxgZiQmaNGGtfFIrQovQGdEhAZYhw3OGpRxwQVwGixKLE+RCllRCHUqFq+kKCylBy5flExL201lCpVGou1V0lqLCj-XTUQxwDZuloAdUkAAsIPwYGCAiraXNI+bqChvgE+iFSFb1GX9aE4CczgFqIIvFA4LljU44e4vLwAgAiAByJaQ-ZxrnZ9EODd5oocslssgA9LY4Uul65N3AAHo+LlgFBQEdFa4zvlFkc14J14DVwK1ytnpst+iV-K5aOx+OJiMyVMwNMczgPNoXdC9S3va9K1vK9TEfHk+WbEBW3bTtljcTxvAHYdvjHJkogHM88InJEpy5M85zgBdl1XVx1y3Tdd33Q9j3oU8EOfZDX3ID9-gVJU4AAWWsWoGluLsVmsAdi1wtlSM5blG0g0xKIlD4vh+PI4DNfCpLgftb37OS9mnDjlJCVSXnU6VNJ47SJJtPT+yI4yOVMpSkNbSzJQ02U7J0yS1gyRotjhScFKfJw4BkvlyxvO84vgjyXygN9vOsmVfh4oA)